# Send email from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm building a very basic iOS app with Swift 3. It consists on a formulary with this fields:

- Name
- Last name
- Email
- Phone
- City (Picker View)
- Description

I want to send this data with an email. Using field Email as a receiver, and the rest of the fields in the Body.

I want the sender always be the same, I have a Wordpress backend, I don't know if I must have endpoint to do this (maybe sending mail with PHP, not from the App directly).

I tried to use MFMailComposeViewController, but this open the modal to send an email, and requires to configure an email account on the device.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you either need a webservice endpoint to do this otherwise you have to configure email account in iPhone and use that

Comment: You need to design service which takes data form iOS and in backend use any mailchip service to send mail through same sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send your data to your web server using web service and from there send an e-mail to Receiver/Recipients. Web server can send e-mail without notifying (mobile app) user.

You can setup an account on web server that can send all e-mails from a single account. In your case, sending emails from web server using web service would be best choice.

> iOS won't allow to send an e-mail without using
>   **`MFMailComposeViewController`**.

Answer (score 2):

You need a service to deliver your emails, this can be your own WebService or you can choose one of the many available services, like [sendgrid.com](http://sendgrid.com) which is fairly easy to implement in your Swift app and has a 40k email limit for free.

Here is a **Swift 3** example using [sendgrid.com](http://sendgrid.com) service:

Note: before you use this method, signup at [sendgrid.com](http://sendgrid.com) to get the `api_user` and `api_key` values.

```
func sendEmail(_ email: String, recipientName: String, subject: String, text: String) {
    let params = [
        "api_user": ENTER_YOUR_API_USER,
        "api_key": HERE_YOU_ENTER_API_KEY,
        "to": email,
        "toname": recipientName,
        "subject": subject,
        "html": text,
        "from": "noreply@example.com"
    ]
    var parts: [String] = []
    for (k, v) in params {
        let key = String(describing: k).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        let value = String(describing: v).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        parts.append(String(format: "%@=%@", key!, value!))
    }
    guard let url = URL(string: String(format: "%@?%@", "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json", parts.joined(separator: "&"))) else { return }

    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if (error == nil) {
            print("Email delivered!")
        } else {
            print("Email could not be delivered!")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

**Usage-1 (plain/text)**:

```
sendEmail("recipient@email.com", recipientName: "Recipient Name", subject: "PlainText", text: "This is a PlainText test email.")
```

**Usage-2 (html)**:

```
sendEmail("recipient@email.com", recipientName: "", subject: "HTML Test", text: "<html><div>This is a <b>HTML</b> test email.</div></html>")
```

Comment: Where can I find the API_USER in SendGrid?

Comment: API_USER would be your username, API_KEY your password, check out the api v2 documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

Comment: This does not appear to work. Code was copied and even with "email delivered" there was no email delivered.